# Missing table column, defined in migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to create a new Link table and specified the necessary columns under migration.

under db/migrate

```
class CreateLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :links do |t|
            t.integer :user_id
            t.string :url




            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end


class AddTitleToLink < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # add_column :links, :user_id, :integer
    add_column :links, :title, :string
  end
end
```

When I ran `rails console`, Link returned

```
Link(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, title: string)
```

It seems like `user_id` (the foreign key) and `url` are missing. `Title`, which was added later, is in the table.

Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Do you have two different files, each one with one of these migrations under `db/migrate`? Also, did you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Yup, ran rake db:migrate multiple times. Nick Veys and Igor S. has answered and solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you perhaps run the `CreateLinks` migration before editing it to add the two fields?  If so, you can change that file all day long and `rake db:migrate` will never re-run it.  That would explain there being an empty table `links`, and the field you then added to it in the next migration.

You can step the database back by running `rake db:rollback`.  Try doing that twice, then migrate again.

Comment: I had the same issue and running `rake db:rollback` until the original migration was undone fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can't see any reason for this not to work. Is it possible that you first ran:

```
rails g model Link
```

(which generated a migration AND RAN it)

and then you manually added the :url and :user_id?

Try running twice:

```
rake db:rollback
```

Then run again

```
rake db:migrate
```

which will catch up your manual modifications

Comment: Noticed your answer when finished writing my own. :)

Comment: Thanks guys. That solved it. I can't select both answers as correct though :( Had to pick the first one.